# How to view leaks of Activities and Classes in Android Studio 1.5

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I had downloaded the android-studio 1.5 new version from the following link

[Here is the link](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/1-5-preview-1)

I want to view the leaks in the activity and class. I'm struggling to find that tool, please anyone could help me out this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) library in your project to trace the leaks in your application. It is very easy to integrate

Answer (score 0):

from http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/studio.html:

> Added new Memory Monitor analysis abilities to Android Monitor. When
>   you view an HPROF file captured from this monitor, the display is now
>   more helpful so you can more quickly locate problems, such as memory
>   leaks. To use this monitor, click Android Monitor at the bottom of the
>   main window. In Android Monitor, click the Memory tab. While the
>   monitor is running, click the Dump Java Heap icon, and then click
>   Captures in the main window and double-click the file to view it. (The
>   Android Device Monitor can't be running at the same time as Android
>   Monitor.)